# element in character array is replaced by '?'

Tags: java, arrays, ascii

I am modifying array like this. But the lower case characters are replaced by '?'. This could be a very basic mistake but I am not able to get it.

```
String s = new String("ndkcnNKDNKCNnknd");
char[] a = s.toCharArray();
char c;
System.out.println(a[2]);
for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    if(a[i] >= 'A'){
        a[i] = (char)(a[i]-'A'+'a');
    }
}

s = String.copyValueOf(a);
System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
k  
?????nkdnkcn????
```

Comment: what do you expect ? what don't you understand ?

Comment: What *other* output did you expect? Why?

Comment: The ASCII code for uppercase 'A' is 65 (0x41), and the ASCII code for lowercase 'a' is 97 (0x61). Your lowercase letters match `a[i]>='A'`, and therefore will be modified by your script.

Comment: Also, do you need to handle characters such as `'<'` `'='` `'>'` `'^'`?

Answer (score 5):

'a' is bigger 'A'. Note that *index/position* in [Unicode Table](https://unicode-table.com/en/) of 'a' is [97](https://unicode-table.com/en/0061/) (or 0x61 if yo prefer hexadecimal system) while 'A' is [65](https://unicode-table.com/en/0041/) (0x41 in hexadecimal).

So if we compare `'a' > 'A'` it is same as comparing `97 > 65`.

Example:

```
System.out.println((int)'a'); //97
System.out.println((int)'A'); //65
System.out.println('a'>'A');  //true
```

This means that our condition `if(a[i] >= 'A')` also includes all lowercase characters like `'a'` `'b'`.

To handle only uppercase characters either

- change `>='A'` into `< 'a'`
- OR add second condition for "maximal" accepted character, like `if (a[i]>='A' && a[i]<='Z')`

```
String s = new String("ndkcnNKDNKCNnknd");
char[] a = s.toCharArray();
//char c;
//System.out.println(a[2]);
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] < 'a') {
        a[i] = (char) (a[i] - 'A' + 'a');
    }
}
s = String.copyValueOf(a);
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: thank you so much for your time sir. That was really silly from me.

Comment: @shanfeng I edited your answer to add more details and alternative (hopefully more readable) approach. Hope you don't mind (but if you do feel free to rollback my edit to your version in [revision of edits to your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72965005/revisions)).

Answer (score 1):

When string is comprised from lower case and upper case English letters condition `a[i] >= 'A'` is always `true`. Hence you're altering both lower case and upper case letter in the array.

You can fix the code and make it more expressive by using `Character.isUpperCase` and `Character.toLowerCase`.

```
String source = "ndkcnNKDNKCNnknd";
char[] characters = source.toCharArray();
        
for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
    if (Character.isUpperCase(characters[i])) {
        characters[i] = Character.toLowerCase(characters[i]);
    }
}
    
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(characters));
```